# Adding Items in one page to the shopping cart which will be displayed in another page using only JS/CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Since I am not allowed to use any back-end code, how should I fullfill this function? I've searched lots of tutorials but usually the items and shopping cart are in same page.
Someone says Jquery.load() can be used here, but I'm not sure how it can be done

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about setting cookies with JS?

Comment: Cookie or localStorage … (But without any form of backend, who is going to _process_ what I have put into my cart eventually …?)

Comment: Encode item into query string parameters and open new page by url with that parameters and then read parameters from opened page location url

Comment: try using https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb

Comment: [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is your best bet. Be aware, `localStorage` is cleared in `Incognito`.

Comment: @Jacob-JanMosselman if you are using cookies, how would you retrieve it in another page?All I saw was within same page tho

Answer (score 1):

I would use the LocalStorage feature.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

On the item page:

```
var cartItems = localStorage.getItem('cartItems');

cartItems.push(newItem);

localStorage.setItem('cartItems', cartItems);
```

Then on the cart page:

```
var cartItems = localStorage.getItem('cartItems');
//Do whatever you're going to do with the contents of the cart.
```

From an application design standpoint, a better solution, if you're really building a storefront application, is probably to work with whoever works on the server side of the application to add a server-side session feature that can store the cart contents.

Comment: Thank you, I see you points, but how would you store a HTML element with localStorage.getItem()? should I put id of that element inside the parentheses ?

Comment: @ZihanChen just store the data (item, quantity, etc..). Then just have a function that takes the data object and builds a string of the html element, then append to a parent control using jquery `append`